# How to remove and fill in NAs

Tags: r, na, data-cleaning

Let's say I have a dataframe with one observation:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, NA, 4, 21, 43, 19, 21, NA, NA, 53, 54, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

How do I replace the NA that are sandwiched between numbers with the value above the NA (i.e. 3 and 21) and remove NAs that are not sandwiched? I need to be able to remove non-sandwiched NAs without specifying the row number because I need to do this for many dataframes with variable rows.

I want to end up with this:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, *3*, 4, 21, 43, 19, 21, *21*, *21*, 53, 54))
```

Now how do I do this, but instead of using the value above the NA to replace the NA, I use a value that is an average of the value above and below the NA like this:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, *3.5*, 4, 21, 43, 19, 21, *37*, *37*, 53, 54))
```

Comment: `na.locf(na.trim(a$x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf0` from `zoo` to fill up the `NA` with the previous non-NA element while creating a logical index with the cumulative sum of `is.na` to remove the NAs at the end

```
library(zoo)
i1 <- cumsum(!is.na(a$x))
na.locf0(a$x)[i1 != max(i1)| !duplicated(i1)]
#[1]  1  3  3  4 21 43 19 21 21 21 53 54
```

Comment: Hi akrun. Thanks! This solves the problem for the sandwiched NAs, but creates another problem which is that the NAs I want removed  (the ones at the end) now contain the previous non-NA element.

Comment: @Drew Thank you for the comments.  Can you check now

Comment: Works like a charm! Any chance you know a way to average the sandwiched NAs rather than using the previous non_NA element?

Comment: @Drew In that case, you can use `na.spline` or `na.approx`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you